# Is a UIWebView the best way to display formatted text in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I want to display formatted text in my iOS app and I have a lot of it (about as much text as a medium sized wikipedia entry) is a WebView with html the best way to display formatted text or is there a better way? I read on stackOverflow that WebViews suck a lot of memory, is that true? How does wikipedia display all of its text in its iOS app?

Comment: You can use attributed text too, it supports formatting(even HTML formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you should use `UITextView` or `UILabel` to display formatted text is that there is no ultimate way to get content bounds at the first time it is drawn in `UIWebView`.

You can use UIKit object whichever you can render `NSAttributedString` such as `UITextView` or `UILabel`.

If your content is `html` you can convert it to `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, you are saying instead of a UIWebView with html I could use a UITextView with NSAttributed text and this will be able to format text in the same way html does?

Comment: @BenNalle There can be pros and cons. If you content contains multimedia (especially video) or async contents, those will be hard to presented in `UITextView`. However if your content is more like just formatted text and hyper links, using UITextView+NSAttributedString will be more native way.

Comment: What do you mean by async contents? I apologize I am new to coding. The NSAttributedString I would use to populate the UITextView would be retrieved via a Firebase Database request would that not be ok?

Comment: @BenNalle Sometimes web content is fetched asynchronously but not your case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a WKWebView with a contrained height and width. That way I could load the HTML without any additional set up and I didn't run into any problems with the web views bounds.